# Flask-SocketIO not connecting to WebSocket after deploying to Heroku

Tags: javascript, python, heroku, websocket, flask-socketio

I am trying to create a real-time chatroom application using Flask-SocketIO. The app seems to work as intended when running on my local machine, however after deploying the app to Heroku the websocket won't connect and I get two errors:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://cs50flack.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?
EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=8f8e233608794661a113fadc5418c27f' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

and:

```
GET https://cs50flack.herokuapp.com/socket.io/? 
EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1546556762105- 
66&sid=b17b8d48610842fca97cbac3e030f3bd 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

code: https://github.com/r0ss26/Flack
URL: https://cs50flack.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Run your server with logging enabled and check if there are any more specific error messages in the log afterwards.

Comment: same problem.. how yo resolved it?!